# Cross compiling openvswitch for android

Tags: compiler-errors, android-ndk, makefile, android-source, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile the Openvswitch for android.
I follow the instructions from here https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1k5jAkz_R475Ohj0OaJdWwSpAw6mmR2Mp_Ggr8_yrXsY .

**Kernel version**

I have downloaded and built successfully the omap kernel for Galaxy nexus following the instructions from https://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html.
The kernel is located in my desktop in the folder /home/zoe/AOSP/omap. The kernel is 3.0.72 version.

I have downloaded the Android NDK r5b, so as to use the cross-compiler from toolchain arm-eabi-4.4.0.

**OpenVswitch version**

I tried many versions. 1.7.0, 1.9.3, 2.0.0, but all of them give me the same error(openvswitch.ko undefined!) .

**Initialize enviornment**

First i run the following commands

```
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/zoe/android-ndk-r5b
export ANDROID_KERNEL=/home/zoe/AOSP/omap
```

Then i set the PATH so as the cross-compiler can be found:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/zoe/android-ndk-r5b/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin


cd openvswitch-2.0.0
```

Then i generate the configure file:

```
./boot.sh
```

Then, i run configure:

```
./configure --host=arm-eabi CC=arm-eabi-gcc CPPFLAGS="-I$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/" CFLAGS="-nostdlib" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/ -L$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/" LIBS="-lc " ovs_cv_use_linker_sections=no --with-l26=$ANDROID_KERNEL KARCH=arm --with-rundir=/data/local/var
```

When i do `ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- make` in the openvswitch folder, at the Building modules stage 2 i get many errors and warnings saying that the openvswitch.ko is undefined:

**Error message**

```
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "register_netdevice" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kmem_cache_destroy" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kmalloc_caches" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__kmalloc" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "skb_gso_segment" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "register_pernet_device" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "_raw_spin_unlock" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "del_timer" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "strlen" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "rcu_barrier" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "genl_unregister_family" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "autoremove_wake_function" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "ip_local_out" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "get_random_bytes" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "netdev_rx_handler_register" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "rtnl_lock" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "skb_copy_and_csum_dev" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "dst_release" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "_raw_spin_lock_bh" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "skb_clone" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "dev_get_by_name" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "_find_next_bit_le" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "register_netdevice_notifier" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__alloc_percpu" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "inet_proto_csum_replace4" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sock_create_kern" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "mutex_unlock" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "call_rcu" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "crc32c" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kthread_create_on_node" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "jiffies" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "free_percpu" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "unregister_netdevice_notifier" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "skb_trim" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "strcmp" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "netif_rx" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__pskb_pull_tail" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__init_waitqueue_head" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "nr_cpu_ids" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "nla_memcpy" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "wait_for_completion" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__memzero" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "nlmsg_notify" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "memset" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "net_namespace_list" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "skb_checksum" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "random32" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "jiffies_to_msecs" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "printk" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "ethtool_op_get_link" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kthread_stop" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "memcmp" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "unregister_pernet_device" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "ipv6_ext_hdr" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__skb_warn_lro_forwarding" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "nla_find" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "free_netdev" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "strncpy" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "nla_put" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "_raw_spin_unlock_irq" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "strlcpy" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kmem_cache_free" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "warn_slowpath_null" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "skb_push" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "mutex_lock" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "dev_get_by_index_rcu" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__skb_get_rxhash" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sk_free" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "netlink_unicast" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__rcu_read_unlock" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "add_timer" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "genl_register_family_with_ops" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "skb_pull" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "init_net" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "flex_array_get" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "ksize" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__do_div64" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "boot_tvec_bases" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "local_bh_disable" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__secpath_destroy" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kmem_cache_alloc" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__nla_reserve" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__alloc_skb" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sk_release_kernel" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "netlink_broadcast" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "_raw_spin_unlock_bh" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "nla_parse" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "cpu_possible_mask" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "netdev_rx_handler_unregister" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "skb_checksum_help" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "schedule" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kfree_skb" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "_raw_spin_lock_irq" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "local_bh_enable" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "alloc_netdev_mqs" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "eth_type_trans" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__bug" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "wake_up_process" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "pskb_expand_head" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "ether_setup" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kmem_cache_alloc_trace" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "_raw_spin_lock" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__per_cpu_offset" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "_raw_spin_lock_irqsave" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "nf_conntrack_destroy" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "skb_pull_rcsum" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kmem_cache_create" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "unregister_netdevice_queue" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "ip_route_output_flow" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "ktime_get_ts" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__wake_up" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "net_ratelimit" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "netlink_set_err" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "flex_array_free" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kthread_should_stop" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "dev_set_promiscuity" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kfree" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "memcpy" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "prepare_to_wait" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kernel_bind" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "genl_register_mc_group" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "flex_array_alloc" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "finish_wait" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "_set_bit" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "nla_reserve" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "complete" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "_test_and_set_bit" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "memmove" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "csum_partial" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "consume_skb" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "dev_queue_xmit" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__rcu_read_lock" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "_clear_bit" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "skb_put" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "skb_copy_bits" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "inet_get_local_port_range" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "rtnl_unlock" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__ip_select_ident" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__nla_put" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "flex_array_prealloc" [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.ko] undefined!
  CC      /home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.o
/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.c:8: error: variable '__this_module' has initializer but incomplete type
/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.c:9: error: unknown field 'name' specified in initializer
/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.c:9: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.c:9: warning: (near initialization for '__this_module')
/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.c:10: error: unknown field 'init' specified in initializer
/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.c:10: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.c:10: warning: (near initialization for '__this_module')
/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.c:14: error: unknown field 'arch' specified in initializer
/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.c:14: error: 'MODULE_ARCH_INIT' undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.c:14: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.c:14: warning: (near initialization for '__this_module')
make[5]: *** [/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux/openvswitch.mod.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/zoe/AOSP/omap'
make[3]: *** [default] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath/linux'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0/datapath'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zoe/openvswitch-2.0.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can't understand what's going wrong. I couldn't find a solution in web.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solved your problem!?

Comment: I did not solve the problem for kernel versions prior to 3.4.
The openvswitch.ko already exists in android kernels from 3.4 version and greater. However, you should activate it by running make config.
All the android versions from Kitkat and after have kernel version >= 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to compile ovs kernel mode against Android KitKat for the past days. Finally, I made it with many trials and errors. I ran into your problem, and wish my solution will help anyone else who needs a remedy for this, although this post is old.

Basically, main error in your ovs compilation is the '__this_module' is not found. Common solution found online (enabling the LOADABLE_MODULES=y in .config in Android kernel directory) for this problem is not effective. The reason for that is ovs is not referring to the .config file when being configuration and when running *make*. **After enabling 'LOADABLE_MODULES', you need to use your ndk or Android toolchains to compile the Android kernel first, to let the new conf take effect.** Then you can compile your ovs, the '__this_module' error will be gone.